# Wordpress - Jquery Not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have added a jquery to my page with the following code in the functions.php

```
wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js', false, '1.9.1', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

This worked for sometime. After that it shows jQuery not defined

have I done something wrong here? Should I do it any otherway??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use:

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
```

then:

```
wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js', false, '1.9.1', false);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

and in header.php use:

```
wp_head();
```

before `</head>` tag.
And i think it is better to put jquery into `<head>` tag. Remember all you javascript dependent on jquery have to be linked after jquery core.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has it's own `jquery library` so you do not need to include it. If you include the `library` of jquery then at some situation it may `conflict with wordpress` library.
I used jquery many times in my plugins and I always use this method
`wp_register_script('script', plugins_url('script.js', __FILE__));`
`wp_enqueue_script('script');`
I think this helps.